# How to add controls for the Auto resizing label based on height and width in .Net Maui

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-maui.shell

I have a frame of Height & Width is 50 and i have added label "Test" it should have been in greater size, if i have add "TestTheAutoSize" it should auto adapt the size of font based on width and height of frame.

Comment: Try to wrap the Label with a Stacklayout, maybe set width as well

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to an event for the `Frame`'s SizeChanged property and write the following event code in the behind code

```
private void Frame_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the frame size
    var frameWidth = Frame.Width;
    var frameHeight = Frame.Height;

    // Set the minimum and maximum values for the font size
    var minFontSize = 10;
    var maxFontSize = 30;

    //The fontsize can be adjusted according to the width of the frame, '10' means the ratio and you could change the ratio according to your needs.
    var fontSize = Math.Min(maxFontSize, Math.Max(minFontSize, frameWidth / 10));

    // Set the font size of the label
    Label.FontSize = fontSize;
}
```